# How to use reflection in Portable Class Library for Windows Store/WP8/WinRT?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I need to find an equivelent to the following code for use in a portable library:

```
    Public Overridable Function GetPropertyValue(ByVal p_propertyName As String) As Object
        Dim bf As System.Reflection.BindingFlags
        bf = Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
        Dim propInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = Me.GetType().GetProperty(p_propertyName, bf)
        Dim tempValue As Object = Nothing

        If propInfo Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Try
            tempValue = propInfo.GetValue(Me, Nothing)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Errors.Add(New Warp10.Framework.BaseObjects.BaseErrorMessage(String.Format("Could not Get Value from Property {0}, Error was :{1}", p_propertyName, ex.Message), -1))
            Return Nothing
        End Try

        Return tempValue

    End Function
```

The BindingFlags don't seem to exist.  The System.Reflection.PropertyInfo is a valid type, but I can't figure out how to fill it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Windows 8/Windows Phone 8, a lot of this Reflection functionality has been moved to a new TypeInfo class. You can find more information [in this MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh535795.aspx). For information including the runtime properties (including those that are inherited for example), you can use the new [RuntimeReflectionExtensions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.reflection.runtimereflectionextensions.aspx) as well (where filtering can be done simply via LINQ).

Though this is C# code (my apologies :)), here is something fairly equivalent using this new functionality:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object GetPropValue(string propertyName)
    {
        var propInfo = RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperties(this.GetType()).Where(pi => pi.Name == propertyName).First();
        return propInfo.GetValue(this);
    }
}
```

This code is even simpler if you only care about properties declared on the class itself:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object GetPropValue(string propertyName)
    {
        var propInfo = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(propertyName);
        return propInfo.GetValue(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok Jason, I am thoroughly confused. I can't find any of the namespaces or methods above or in the MSDN docs.  What am I missing?  This is a portable Library compatible with.  There is no GetTypeInfo() method on this.GetType() nor can I find RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperties().  The library is targeted to .net4.5, Windows Phone8, and Windows Store.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Win Phone 8 doesn't seem to support these functions.  As soon as I took Silverlight and Win Phone 8 support out, it works.  Is there a WP8 solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't the presence of the Silverlight option that made these disappear? They were first introduced in Windows 8 and my portable library I setup to get this answer included Windows Phone 8 and above and Windows 8 and above.

Comment: Most definitely. Silverlight is totally disabled.  If I add the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio, it retargets the assembly to exclude winphone8.  If I add winPHone8, I get the vbc error.   Are you certain that winphone8 is supported?

Comment: I'll double check mine then. I would think it is supported, but I don't know officially.

Comment: I think it's the "retarget" you mention that is causing the problem. Even after adding WinPhone8, if it is still targeting Silverlight or some down-level framework below Win8/WinPhone8 those APIs won't work. I just created a new Windows Phone project (targeting WinPhone8) and was able to compile using those APIs just fine.

Comment: Yeah.  I opened a ticket with Microsoft.  They say it is an issue and are working with me to resolve it.  I appreciate you getting me started in the right direction.  Thanx.